# Reverse string to find palindromes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, reverse

I have two strings. The first is normal string, the second I want to be a reversed string like first one, but in the console I didn't get the look of like first one listed by commas. How can I fix that ?

Normal string - [image]

Revered string - [image]

```
window.onload = function(){

inputBox = document.getElementById("myText");
btn = document.getElementById('sub');

btn.addEventListener("click",function(event){
event.preventDefault();
    findPalindromes(inputBox.value);   
});

    str = inputBox.value;

    function findPalindromes(str) {

        var words = str.split(" ");
            for (var i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
                words[i] += " ";
            }
        console.log(words);

        var newString = "";
            for (var i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                newString += words[i];
            }
        console.log(newString); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `console.log(words.reverse());`

Comment: The "normal" string is actually an array of strings. If you want the same output, you'll have to create an array for the reversed strings. 

```


```

Comment: `words` is an array. `newString` is a string

Comment: Thanks to all ! :) I have to listen Francisco C and try his way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really just want to find out if a string is a palindrome, you can do something as simple as this:

```
function isPalindrome(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase() === str.toLowerCase().split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want something like this! Thanks! :) But the task is also include to make it with the difficult way.

Answer (score 1):

The first `for` loop is not necessary. You do not need to concatenate a space character `" "` to the element of the array, where the variable assignment `i`

```
var i = 0;
```

and condition

```
i < words.length - 1;
```

stops before reaching last element of array.

```
var newString = "";
for (var i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  newString += words[i] + " ";
}
console.log(newString);
```

Comment: Yes, generally I don't need fist loop, but I use it, because further in the task I will lexicographically compare the two arrays of strings and I have must pull out this words, which are the same, e.g. exe, abba, lamal.

Comment: How will the words the same after you concatenate a space character `" "`?

Comment: Тhe same? What I think is to get the same output, I'll have to create an array for the reversed strings like first one.

Comment: Not sure which arrays you are referencing comparing? What do you mean by "lexicographically compare the two arrays"? Why add the space character to the string within the array if only to display the words at `console`?

Comment: The two arrays will compare - normal and the reversed. "Lexicographically compare the two arrays" will mean compare word by word - first word from first array with first word from the the reversed array etc. and if the words are the same will display it on the console or something like this.

Comment: Why would first word from original array and first word from reversed array be the same?

Comment: They may be be the same or not depends from the text or the sentences and to know we compare them. :)

Comment: @Santiya Not certain how an array compared to the same array having elements revered could have same elements at same index except for one element at middle of two odd `.length` arrays? Though, that is not actual current Question. Actual current Question is _"I didn't get the look of like first one listed by commas. How can I fix that ?"_, which present Answer addresses.

Comment: guest271314 the index doesn't play for the array but his content. And you ask me for the lexicographically compare and I start to explain what is and what I want and think to do. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your "normal" string example, you're printing `words` to the console. Let's first look at what `words` is: `var words = str.split(" ");`

The [String.split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function returns an array of strings. So your "normal" string is actually an array of strings *(The brackets `[]` and comma separated strings in the console output indicate this)*.

In the second example, you're logging `newString`. Let's look at where it comes from: `var newString = "";`

`newString` is a String. If you want it to be an array of strings like `words`, you would declare it with `var newString = [];`. Arrays do not support `+=` so `newString += words[i];` would become `newString.push(words[i]);`

---

The above explains how to get `newString` to behave like `words`, the code you've written is not looking for a palindrome word, but rather a palindrome sentence: "Bob is Bob" is not a palindrome (reversed it is "boB si boB") but it could be a Palindrome sentence (if such a thing exists).

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't know either if such thing exists, but it have to search and compare in text or sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, I wrote this solution for the problem. I hope this is the right answer.

```
window.onload = function(){

inputBox = document.getElementById("myText");
btn = document.getElementById('sub');

btn.addEventListener("click",function(event){
event.preventDefault();
    findPalindromes(inputBox.value);   
});

    str = inputBox.value;

    function findPalindromes(str) { 

        var words = str.split(" "),
            newString = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
            if ((words[i] === words[i].split('').reverse().join('')) === true) {
                newString.push(words[i]);
            }
        }
        console.log(newString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var words = " ";

function reverse_arr(arr){
    var i = arr.length - 1;
    while(i >= 0){
        words += a[i] + " ";
        i--; 
    }
    return words;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.